# How to set up a Storm pseudo distributed cluster

Tags: apache-storm

I have set up a Zookeeper pseudo distributed cluster, and I want to run a Storm topology on a pseudo cluster on my single machine,  what should I do? I have seen someone write that it need to configure Storm 3 times just like dealing with Zookeeper, I`m not sure, does anyone know about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the cluster setup guide:

- https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

For pseudo distributed setup, run all daemons (ZK, Nimbus, and one single supervisor) in your single machine.

Comment: I JUST missed it! Thank you very much.

Comment: thanks what about 127.0.1.1 should i hash it or let it ?

Comment: 127.0.1.1. should have the real name already? If not, try to add another line with the real name.

Comment: i made change in this file before and couldn't restore the defaults ! so what is the real name here you mean do you mean nameofmachine ?

Comment: You should see it in your prompt: `mjsax@T420s-dbis-mjsax:~$`. If not, try `echo $HOSTNAME`. In my case, it returns `T420s-dbis-mjsax`.

Comment: thanks but i'm confused between nameofmachine and hostname , i think it is the same right ?

Comment: ok this if the first point  many thanks for helping , but in storm.yaml should i put in the storm.zookeeper.server and nimbus.host and drpc.server the same ip address which is 127.0.0.1 or can i use text "localhost" ?

Comment: You can use 127.0.0.1 or "hostname". "localhost" will never work. That's the reason why the new line to `/etc/hosts` is required in the first place.

Comment: thanks but still has same problem with port ! org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6703  Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use can i post seperate post for it  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100341/discussion-between-matthias-j-sax-and-begnnier).

Comment: Thx for notice , I have find it myself, so in my config file, I just fill in -_storm.zookeeper.port_ and _supervisor.slots.ports_ . You really helped me a lot @Matthias J. Sax